# jquery ajax abort

Tags: jquery

I am working on kind of a autocomplete searching option and for that I have used `jquery's abort function` because I need to abort the previous call and let the new call begin on every `keypress` below is the code

```
if(ajaxCall) ajaxCall.abort();
ajaxCall = $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/' + target,
    beforeSend: function() {},
    complete: function() {},
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result) {
        ....
    }
});
```

though its working fine but, am concerned about its usage if its fine to use this method or not because i can see a lots of aborted calls in the firebug console? I think the aborted call is not literally aborted from the server but, only from the browser am I right?.

Is there any other alternate to this approach to or is it fine to use this?

Comment: Sending a new request on very keypress is a horrible idea. Sounds like you want a debouncing plugin so the request is only sent when the user stops typing.

Comment: @ThiefMaster it means my concern was valid, this isn't even a fair solution right? can you please name some debouncing plugins? have never heard of any

Comment: Underscore.js contains a function for it.

Comment: ... and theres a jQuery `debounce` plugin; http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

Comment: Thanks guys, your help is appreciated! let me give it a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP connection will be terminated when you call `abort()`. Whether or not this stops your PHP script (it looks like you're using CodeIgniter) depends on your server setup, but the default is to, yes.

Regardless of whether the server completes the request or not though, its result will *never* be sent to the client,  so the results will never be *displayed*.

However, I'd ask *why* you're aborting every request. If I was coding the auto complete, I'd either detect a period of inactivity (e.g. the user stopping typing) before sending the request, *or* allow the requests to complete and show; *some* results (even if they're 1 char old) is better than no results, right?

Comment: yes its CI, ` its result will never be sent to the client, so the results will never be displayed` does this mean there is a possibility that the call will go to web server in any case? can you give any idea on how to get that `inactivity period` please

Comment: @Junaid: Yes, *when* it gets aborted depends on how quickly the user presses the next key; it could be *before* the connection was established, during the request, or even *after*.

Comment: @Junaid: The inactivity period can be calculated using a simple `setTimeout` in the keypress, or you can use a plugin for it, such as http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

Comment: Thanks @Matt let me give it a try